# Send data between activities

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Java & Android Studio. I need to send data between activities. But
I have 3 activities. `A` -> `B` -> `C`

I want to send a data from `A` to `C` directly without write anything in B.
Hope you understood. Have a nice day and thanks.

Comment: can you explain with a scenario. This is unusual case. You can store data in a singleton class and can access anywhere in your app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what type of data you want to pass.

1. The first way is to use static global variable. You are able to pass any type you want, but this way is fragile as the object that you are passing is saved in memory (not disk). It can lead to [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).
2. The second way is to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). With this, your data will be saved on disk.